# how do you extract a certain part of a URL in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, url

I am looking to extract only a portion of a patterned URL:

```
https://<some_server>/server/rest/services/<that part I need>/<other data I do not need>/...
```

I just need to extract the portion after 'rest/services/' the first part can change, the last part can change, but the URL will always have 'rest/services/' and what I need follows, followed by '/...

Comment: please, check the standard library first, you will find: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html and here an example: https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/09/python-urlparse-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is turn this string into a list by splitting it, and then access the nth part.

```
m = 'https://<some_server>/server/rest/services/<that part I need>/<other data I do not need>'
a = m.split('/')
a[6] //This is the part that you want
```

Comment: What if the prefix to the pattern I know will be there is different, i.e. more /something/something/...?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
(?<=rest/services/) # look behind for this
[^/]+               # anything except a '/'

import re
rgxp = re.compile(r'(?<=rest/services/)[^/]+')
print re.findall(rgxp, text)
```